# Nuxt Vuetify Module - Custom Component icons does't work

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

**Module version**
@nuxtjs/vuetify - 1.8.3
nuxt 2.9.2

**Describe the bug**
Importing of custom created component icons is impossible.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#component-icons

**To Reproduce**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-vuetify-z42mm

Steps to reproduce the behavior:
1. On index.vue, there are few icons.
 
Custom created icon Is not shown. No errors, no warnings.

**Expected behaviour**
I am expecting to have access to a custom icon with $vuetify.icons.values.ionic but this component was not created in $vuetify.icons object.

Also, it is not possible to change vuetify font from vuetify.options.js like this:

```
icons: {
  iconfont: 'fa4',
  values: {
    customIcon: customIconComponent
  }
}
```

Maybe they are related...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it with Minaro response :

- My vuetify configuration wasn't in a separated file but in *nuxt.config.js*.
- I had to put "@nuxtjs/vuetify" in the *buildModules* list because of the treeShake option.
- But then my custom icons were not loaded/accessible
- I put "@nuxtjs/vuetify" in the *modules* list too

But now, separating the vuetify configuration solves the problem:

*nuxt.config.js* :

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/vuetify"],

vuetify: {
   optionsPath: "./plugins/vuetify.js",
   customVariables: ["~/assets/css/variables.scss"],
   treeShake: true
}
```

*vuetify.js* :

```
import MyCustomIcon from "~/components/MyCustomIcon.vue";

export default {
  theme: { ...},
  icons: {
    values: {
        myCustomIcon: {
            component: MyCustomIcon,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use custom icons : 
*nuxt.config*

```
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    optionsPath: '~/plugins/vuetify.js',
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

and :
*plugins/vuetify.js*

```
import Redux from '~/components/icons/redux.vue'
import ReduxSaga from '~/components/icons/redux-saga.vue'
import Jwt from '~/components/icons/jwt.vue'
import Express from '~/components/icons/express.vue'
import MongoDB from '~/components/icons/mongodb.vue'
import Sdl from '~/components/icons/sdl.vue'
import Webpack from '~/components/icons/webpack.vue'
import Yarn from '~/components/icons/yarn.vue'


export default {
  icons: {
    values: {
      redux: {
        component: Redux,
      },
      saga: {
        component: ReduxSaga,
      },
      jwt: {
        component: Jwt,
      },
      express: {
        component: Express,
      },
      mongodb: {
        component: MongoDB,
      },
      sdl: {
        component: Sdl,
      },
      webpack: {
        component: Webpack,
      },
      yarn: {
        component: Yarn,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- Add options path in Nuxt Vuetify config, e.g. `optionsPath: '~/plugins/vuetify.js'`.
- Add a `plugins/vuetify.js` file that exports the icons, e.g.:

```js
import SearchIcon from '~/components/icons/SearchIcon.vue'

export default {
  icons: {
    values: {
      search: {
        component: SearchIcon,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- The defined icons will now be available with `$vuetify.icons` prefix, for example:

```html
<v-icon>$vuetify.icons.search</v-icon>
```